# How can I play the caller's name in Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I am using Google Voice with their Call Screening function. It works well when I answer the phone that my calls forward to: I hear "You have an call from {caller name}" but I am looking for a way to get caller's names *after* they call, using the web UI or the app.

It used to be that I could go to the Legacy UI and click the little speaker next to a caller's number and it would play their name, but this no longer appears to work.

How can I hear the caller's name using Call Screening in the Google Voice web UI or app?